# Error while Trying to Hook "TerminateProcess" Function. Target Process crashes. Can anyone help me?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Debugging with visual studio 2005 The following Error Displayed :

> Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in procexp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000000.

And Thread Information:

> 2704    Win32 Thread    00000000    Normal  0

```
extern "C" VDLL2_API BOOL WINAPI MyTerminateProcess(HANDLE hProcess,UINT uExitCode)
{
     SetLastError(5);
     return FALSE;
}

FARPROC HookFunction(char *UserDll,FARPROC pfn,FARPROC HookFunc) 

{
    DWORD dwSizeofExportTable=0;
    DWORD dwRelativeVirtualAddress=0;
    HMODULE hm=GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    FARPROC pfnOriginalAddressToReturn;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pim=(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hm;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pimnt=(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)pim + 
(DWORD)pim->e_lfanew); 
    PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY 
pimdata=(PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY)&(pimnt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory);

    PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER pot=&(pimnt->OptionalHeader);
    PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY 
pim2=(PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY)((DWORD)pot+(DWORD)104);
    dwSizeofExportTable=pim2->Size;
    dwRelativeVirtualAddress=pim2->VirtualAddress;
    char *ascstr;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR 
pimexp=(PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(pim2->VirtualAddress + (DWORD)pim);
    while(pimexp->Name)
    {
        ascstr=(char *)((DWORD)pim + (DWORD)pimexp->Name);
        if(strcmpi(ascstr,UserDll) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        pimexp++;
    }
    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA 
pname=(PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD)pim+(DWORD)pimexp->FirstThunk);
    LPDWORD lpdw=&(pname->u1.Function);
    DWORD dwError=0;
    DWORD OldProtect=0;
    while(pname->u1.Function)
    {
        if((DWORD)pname->u1.Function == (DWORD)pfn)
        {
            lpdw=&(pname->u1.Function);

VirtualProtect((LPVOID)lpdw,sizeof(DWORD),PAGE_READWRITE,&OldProtect);


            pname->u1.Function=(DWORD)HookFunc;

VirtualProtect((LPVOID)lpdw,sizeof(DWORD),PAGE_READONLY,&OldProtect);

            return pfn;
        }
        pname++;

    }
    return (FARPROC)0;
}


FARPROC CallHook(void) 
{
        HMODULE hm=GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Kernel32.dll"));
    FARPROC fp=GetProcAddress(hm,"TerminateProcess");
    HMODULE hm2=GetModuleHandle(TEXT("vdll2.dll"));
    FARPROC fpHook=GetProcAddress(hm2,"MyTerminateProcess");

    dwAddOfTerminateProcess=HookFunction("Kernel32.dll",fp,fpHook);
    if(dwAddOfTerminateProcess == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Unable TO Hook Function."),TEXT("Parth"),MB_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Success Hooked."),TEXT("Parth"),MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

004118AC  mov         esi,esp
004118AE  push        0
004118B0  mov         eax,dword ptr [hProc]
004118B3  push        eax
004118B4  call        dword  ptr[__imp__TerminateProcess@8(4181E4h)]
004118BA  cmp         esi,esp

`esi` returned zero. why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is VDLL2_API defined as? It may be interfering with the calling convention (which is meant to be WINAPI for this function, as you write it later on the same line).

Stack problems on exit (ESI, ESP) usually indicate that you have your calling conventions mixed up. You appear to have used `FARPROC` consistently everywhere else, but since you know the exact prototype of the function, try `typedef`-ing that as the type to use instead:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC)(HANDLE, UINT);
```

Now use `TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC` everywhere instead of `FARPROC`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write this kind of code yourself.  Use the [Detours library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) from Microsoft Research.

Comment: I know that i should not write this kind of code myself.
But I am writing it for experimental purposes, and to see that I am able to write this kind of code. I want to know about the bug in the Program.Anyway,Thank you for answering my Question.

Comment: You can't write code like this if you don't know how to debug it.  It should be part of the experiment perhaps.  Somebody else debugging this for you doesn't help you write and debug this kind of code in the future.  Good luck!

Comment: I know how to debug this kind of program and i am debugging it for last two days. But I have not found any bug so I am asking in stackoverflow .Anyway I have found some interesting information during debugging That have been added to the Question. Take a Look.

Comment: The compiler expects the called function to preserve the value of the esi register.  That's not happening for the redirected function.  Not sure why, look at the assembly code of the replacement function.  The compiler might have optimized it, passing the arguments through registers.  Because it doesn't have external linkage perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant: Maybe someone would want to write `"this kind of code yourself"` to avoid restrictions of licensing terms of the Detours project -- `"Detours Express 3.0 is available for immediate download under a no-fee license for research, non-commercial, and non-production use. Detours Express may be used to prototype (but not deploy) commercial projects"`

Comment: Detours 4 has been published under an MIT license since 2016, covered in [the faq](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours/wiki/FAQ).